# Managin friends in mysql database for social networking site

Tags: php, mysql, social-networking, friend

I have long been searching for an answer to this watched a few videos but I can't seem to find an good answer. I want to make a friend system on my site. I have currently set up a many to many system I think is right. Am I supposed to have one database per member containing all their friends?

but my main problem is when I get all the friend id. how do I get their name? I can connect to the database once for each member using this.

```
<?php foreach ($friend as $person) {
friend_names[] = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT username FROM users WHERE id='$person'");
} ?>
```

But is there not a simpler way to do it all in one query. I have tried using the different joins but then its write down all the name in the database not just the logged on users friends. so then I would have to use one database per member containing friends id. and also when I use

```
SELECT users.username
FROM relationships
INNER JOIN users ON relationships.user_1 = users.id
```

It adds my username too. could anyone explain how I should do this. so I don't have to sit listen to people on youtube explaining how a function works :S?

DB for the relationships

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `relationships` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_1` int(11) NOT NULL,
`user_2` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

Comment: Please post your db schema. And a `JOIN` is probably the way to go here

Comment: _“Am I supposed to have one database per member”_ – _what?_ Of course not. // You should go learn more about the _basics_ of handling data with SQL, because it sounds like you know where little as of now.

Comment: I have added the db. CBroe. I do know enough that its stupid but I can't find a way to do it with one DB.

the user information is in an DB called users which contain more info but the importance in it related to this is username and id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select users.username 
from relationships 
inner join users on relationships.user_2=users.id     
and relationships.user_1=2;
```

you will need to use this in your database. you just change the code at the end (relationships.user_1=2) with your session user id :)

edit:
to get it all In one query. I also added a row for status (blocked, friend, pending request):

```
SELECT users.username
FROM relationships 
INNER JOIN users ON ((relationships.user_1 = users.id AND relationships.user_2='$user')
or (relationships.user_2 = users.id AND relationships.user_1='$user'))
and relationships.status=1
```